# R: list.files() does not find files in "special folder"

Tags: r, fs

I have the following problem: I want to list all files recursively in a given folder. But this folder contains a somehow special folder, where `list.files()` can't look into. However, `fs::dir_ls()` is able to look into the folder. See the example:

```
> list.files(path, recursive = TRUE)
[1] "???"                               "archive_folders.R"                
[3] "archived_folder/archived_file.txt"
> 
> dir_ls(path, recurse = TRUE)
U:/Eigene Dateien/R/archive_folders/archive_folders.R
U:/Eigene Dateien/R/archive_folders/archived_folder
U:/Eigene Dateien/R/archive_folders/archived_folder/archived_file.txt
U:/Eigene Dateien/R/archive_folders/ааа
U:/Eigene Dateien/R/archive_folders/ааа/archived_file.txt
```

I'm working on Windows 7 and looking into the properties of the `aaa` folder did not give a hint about the problem. So my question is twofold:

1. Any ideas on what might be so special with the `aaa` folder?
2. Is there any possibility that `list.files()` can find the files inside this special folder?

**EDIT:**
The name of the folder `ааа` is in fact *not* `aaa`. Sounds confusing? The folder's name consists of `U+00430`, not the usual letter `a` (`U+0061`).

Comment: Your folder probably has non-ASCII letters in the name. R can be somewhat fragile with special characters on Windows

Comment: That is unlikely. The folders name is `aaa`.

Comment: The fact that `list.files` says it's "???" suggests it's _not_ just `aaa`. How was the folder created?

Comment: Well, the Windows Explorer and `fs::dir_ls()` show the name `aaa`. Unfortunately, I have no information about how the folder was created.

Comment: Relevant perhaps: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoglyph

Comment: Very good hint. Now I am at least able to reproduce the problem with a new folder. So it seems this causes the problem. Any ideas on how to solve it without using `fs`?

Comment: Checking the out put of dir_ls, we see that it is made up of unicode `\u0430` - CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER A.  Suggest renaming by `system('ren ааа aaa')`

Comment: Renaming is not possible. It is not "my" folder...

Comment: Then maybe create a symlink in a folder you do own

Comment: Why not just have another `list.files()` command where you start inside the folder `aaa`? It's not as clean as one command, but if you just need the file...

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar problem. I don't know why but `list.files()` simply didn't work on my previous computer. I solved it using `dir()`. This function is loaded onto base R.

```
dir(path, recursive = TRUE)
```

Otherwise, you can try this to see if changing the working directory changes the result:

```
setwd(path)
dir(, recursive = TRUE)
list.files(, recursive = TRUE)
```

As for your question regarding the folder, I have no idea why this happens.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But `dir()` returns the same as `list.files()`. I thought these were aliases...?

Comment: Well, I have no idea then. I didn't know `dir` and `list.files` were the same either.